# how to use opencv "detectMultiScale()" function in multithreading in raspberry pi

Tags: python, opencv, python-multithreading

detectMultiScale() function of OpenCV python stops responding when I use it in multithreading scenario in raspberry pi 3.

I am hoping to make two threads; one is for showing the live images and another is to detect an object and find its center. Even though the live image showing function runs smoothly its detectMultiScale() function that is not showing any response. I did some online research and found out that OpenCV doesn't handle parallel processing well.

```py
import threading
import cv2
import numpy as np
from picamera.array import PiRGBArray
from picamera import PiCamera
import time
global image, center
center=[]
def capture():
    global image, center
    cv2.namedWindow('image',cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
    cv2.moveWindow('image',0,0)
    cv2.resizeWindow('image', 800,608)
    camera=PiCamera()
    camera.resolution=(800,608)
    camera.framerate=50
    rawCapture=PiRGBArray(camera,size=(800,608))
    for frame in camera.capture_continuous(rawCapture,format='bgr',use_video_port=True):
        image=frame.array      
        cv2.imshow('image',image)

        key=cv2.waitKey(1)& 0xFF
        rawCapture.truncate(0)
        if key==ord('q'):
            break    
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

def detect():
    global image, center
    time.sleep(2)
    drop_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('cascade.xml')
    while True:
        faces = drop_cascade.detectMultiScale(image, 1.25, 7)
        for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
            center.append([x,y,w,h])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    thread1=threading.Thread(target=capture)
    thread2=threading.Thread(target=detect)
    thread1.start()
    thread2.start()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is inherent to `Threads`, it is caused by the Global Interpreter Lock. Threads share the program memory. To protect against conflicts caused by separate threads changing the same variable, Python locks execution to a specific thread. Meaning that at any moment only one thread runs. When the CPU is idle the program switches between threads, making IO-bound applications run faster.

To do CPU heavy tasks simultaneously you have to use `multiprocessing`. Processes run simultaneously on separate CPU cores and do not share memory.

[Here](https://realpython.com/python-gil/) is excellent and more lengthy explanation about the Global Interpreter Lock.

Edit:

[Here](https://www.machinelearningplus.com/python/parallel-processing-python/) is info on multiprocessing.

Example code that compares threads with async multiprocessing:

```
    import time
    import threading
    from  multiprocessing import Pool

    # cpu heavy functions
    def doTask(val):
            for i in range(10000000):
                    x = i*i
            print(str.format('Task {} done!',val))

    def doOtherTask(val):
            for i in range(10000000):
                    x = i*i
            print(str.format('Other Task {} done!',val))

    if __name__ == '__main__':
            print('Threads:')
            # note starttime        
            starttime = time.time()
            # create and run threads
            thread1 = threading.Thread(doTask(1))
            thread2 = threading.Thread(doTask(2))
            thread3 = threading.Thread(doOtherTask(1))
            thread4 = threading.Thread(doOtherTask(2))
            thread1.start()
            thread2.start()
            thread3.start()
            thread4.start()

            print(str.format('Threads took {} seconds', time.time()-starttime))

            print('Multiprocessing:')
            #reset starttime
            starttime = time.time()
            # create and run processes
            arguments = [1,2]
            p = Pool()
            p.map_async(doTask,arguments)
            p.map_async(doOtherTask,arguments)
            # close and join pool, so program execution waits 
            # for all tasks to finish
            p.close()
            p.join()

            print(str.format('Multiprocessing took {} seconds', time.time()-starttime))
```

Comment: I used the multiprocessing package with `process1=Process(target=capture) process2=Process(target=detect) process1.start() and process2.start()` but the problem still remained the same.

Comment: Sorry, that tutorial link wasn't very good. It now links to one that is better, I think. Otherwise, just google around, that's what I do ;) I also provided some example code that you can use as a template.